# Override checkable QGroupBox toggle behaviour

Tags: qt, checkbox, overriding, toggle, qgroupbox

I've subclassed the QGroupBox class, with the checkable property enabled. I'm trying to override the behaviour of the toggle/checked events.

Here's the code:

```
class SideWidgetGroupBox: public QGroupBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SideWidgetGroupBox(QWidget* parent = 0): QGroupBox(parent)
    {
        this->setCheckable(true);
        connect(this, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(my_toggled(bool)));
    }

private slots:
    void my_toggled (bool on)
    {
        std::cout << "my toggled method" <<std::endl;
    }
};
```

So far so good, my slot gets executed. However the groupboxs' contents also get enabled/disabled. Is there a way to prevent that? Or do I have to manually reset the original enabled/disabled state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Is there a way to prevent enabling/disabling of a content?**

Yes, but this way is not easy, because there is no `QCheckBox` there. What looks like a check box is an area of `QGroupBox`. And all events are processed by `QGroupBox`:
1. Override `event` method and prevent processing of `QEvent::KeyRelease` and `QEvent::MouseRelease` events by the base class.

```
bool SideWidgetGroupBox::event(QEvent *e)
{
  switch (e->type()) {
   case QEvent::KeyRelease:
   case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
     myHandler(e);
     return true;
  }
 return QGroupBox::event(e);
}
```

2. In `myHandler` check whether `space` pressed or the mouse clicked on the checkbox. Store checkBox value and do what you need. Use this code to check what is under cursor:

```
QStyleOptionGroupBox box;
initStyleOption(&box);
QStyle::SubControl released = style()->hitTestComplexControl(QStyle::CC_GroupBox, &box,
                                                             event->pos(), this);
bool toggle = released == QStyle::SC_GroupBoxLabel || released == QStyle::SC_GroupBoxCheckBox;
if (toggle)
{
    m_state = !m_state;
    update();
}
```

3. Add method `initStyleOption` and set `state` to the state of the checkBox (you should store it by yourself):

```
void SideWidgetGroupBox::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionGroupBox *option) const
{
    QGroupBox::initStyleOption(option);
    QStyle::State flagToSet = m_state ? QStyle::State_On : QStyle::State_Off;
    QStyle::State flagToRemove = m_state ? QStyle::State_Off : QStyle::State_On;

    option->state |= flagToSet;     
    option->state &= ~flagToRemove;
    option->state &= ~QStyle::State_Sunken;
}
```

4.Method `initStyleOption` in `QGroupBox` is not virtual that is why you need to reimplement `paintEvent` also:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStylePainter paint(this);
    QStyleOptionGroupBox option;
    initStyleOption(&option);
    paint.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_GroupBox, option);
}
```

**do I have to manually reset the original enabled/disabled state?**
You can't do this with `setEnabled` because it checks current checked state and prevents enabling of children. Although you can call `setEnabled` for children directly using `this->findChildren<QWidget*>`

**Suggestion**
You can use ways described above or remove standard checkBox and(or) label and put your own `QCheckBox` over the group (without layout, of course) and use it as you want. If you group can be moved you will need to move the check box also.

Comment: Wow, I tought this would be easier. I'm trying to use your solution, but I can't set the state of the checkBox. I guess this line should do it: `option->state |= (state ? QStyle::State_On : QStyle::State_Off);` , I've tried with true/false values, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @istee Updated 2,3 in the answer. And added 4. There was one more difficulty: initStyleOption is not virtual.

Comment: If I understand all of this correctly, there is no way of using a standard checkable QGroupBox, and overriding the "enable/disable"-behaviour the easy way.  The only possibility would be to re-enable all child widgets one by one?

Comment: You can re-enable the children or use the way described above to remove standard behavior.